# Redmin/Ruby - cannot load such file -- io/wait (LoadError)

Tags: ruby, debian, apache2, passenger, redmine

I'm experiencing some troubles installing Redmine 3 on Debian 7. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/HowTo_Install_Redmine_on_Debian_8_with_Apache2-Passenger) even though it's for Debian 8. I compiled Ruby myself (v2.3.3) and also [passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/apache/install/oss/rubygems_norvm/).

Whenever I try to visit redmine URL I see an error message, and I found this in Apache2 log:

```
[ 2016-12-02 23:15:33.7373 9218/7f42704b4700 age/

Cor/App/Implementation.cpp:304 ]: Could not spawn process for application /opt/redmine: An error occurred while starting up the preloader.
  Error ID: e27a0051
  Error details saved to: /tmp/passenger-error-LnpIIA.html
  Message from application: cannot load such file -- io/wait (LoadError)
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.3.0/socket.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb:30:in `<top (required)>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.3.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/ruby_supportlib/phusion_passenger.rb:235:in `require_passenger_lib'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:77:in `init_passenger'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:155:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/passenger-5.0.30/src/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

As I'm not very familiar with Ruby nor Redmine, can someone explain me how can I address this issue?

Comment: could go and see if there is anything useful in /tmp/passenger-error-LnpIIA.html and the put it here if you find anything and do you have gem rubysl-io-wait installed?